# viewing stack overflow register error

Tags: linux

I am trying to view the esp register in order to understand how stack overflow take place.

I have used `x/8xw $esp` command to view the register, but kept getting error that `Cannot access memory at 0xffffffffffffdf30`.
Can some one please tell me what the problem might be.

I am using Linux 3.13.
I am following the below link to understand registers and stack overflow.
Everything else is working apart from the above mentioned command.
In the video at 10:32 the author can display the esp register, but when I do on my machine, I cant.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RF7DF4kfs1E&index=1&list=PL118A3998B4401EC6

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is, that tutorial is made for x86 architectures.

> "Cannot access memory at 0xffffffffffffdf30"

0xffffffffffffdf30 is 64bit address. While you are on 64bit system, you can't check ESP register, because simply, there isn't.

For example, 64bit systems are using this registers - RSP, RBP, RIP etc.. You can know this registers as ESP, EBP and EIP on x86. So, if you want to go ahead this tutorial, compile that training .c code as 32bit using gcc, like: **gcc -m32 -o demo demo.c**

Comment: Hi Yeez, I try to compile the program as you have suggested but its giving me error saying that "Undefined command: gcc".I am new to stack overflow and I have limited knowledge to computer architectures and system that is the reason I dont know how to go about these errors.Many thanks

Comment: @ZareenaNaz No problem, just try to do this `export CFLAGS=-m32` and compile it again. If problem will still persist, you should install this libc6-dev-i386 package, like: `sudo apt-get install g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386` provided that you are using Ubuntu or Debian distro.

Comment: Hi Yeez, Thank you for your help.Unfortunately there are other errors appearing  when I am trying to install the package as you have suggested.Do you have an email that I can have, so that I ask question through that.